# for in loop in javascript

Tags: javascript

i am trying to understand  following  fragment of  javascript code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p>Click the button to loop through the properties of an object named "person".</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<p id="demo"></p>

<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction()
{
var x;
var txt="";
var person={fname:"John",lname:"Doe",age:25}; 

for (x in person)
{
txt=txt + person[x];
}

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=txt;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

i am a little confused with this line

```
for (x in person)
    {
    txt=txt + person[x];
    }
```

as i  guessed  it is a   associative array,with key--> value relationship and as a final result  should not it print  like this?

```
fname:"John",lname:"Doe",age:25
```

?
thanks very much

Comment: What is `person[x]`? For `x="fname"` we have `person[x]="John"`. The result is `"John" + "Doe" + "25" = "JohnDoe25"`. Think about it. :)

Comment: May help you play around with: [jsconsole](http://jsconsole.com/) 
`
> var txt="";
> var person={fname:"John",lname:"Doe",age:25};
> for (x in person) { txt=txt + person[x]; }
> x
`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, *there is no concept of associate arrays in JavaScript*, the `person` is an object and an object is iterated using the `for-in` loop.

The line:

```
txt = txt + person[x];
```

simply reads each property of the `person` objects and concatenates the value in the `txt` variable giving the result:

```
JohnDoe25
```

---

FYI, always use `for-in` loop for objects and normal `for` loop for arrays.

Answer (score 3):

As said,
javascript has no concept of associative arrays and it is better to do some reading about js than the normal run and test approach because there are some behaviors which is not logically correct untill we learn to think the way js does.

for for..in loops check this https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in and do read the `hasOwnProperty` part . This confuses a lot of people.

I suggest you read http://eloquentjavascript.net/ and whenever have any issues keep checking on MDN. the documentation is really good there.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly `person` is not an `array` it an `object`

secondly `for(x in person)` here `x` is the `key` hence `person[x]` will give the value.

now in line `txt = txt + person[x]` you are just concatenating strings (values and not keys),  so  `txt` will just contain all the `values`

Got beaten by the previous answer by abt 10 seconds :)

Comment: 10 seconds or 2 minutes ? ;-)

Comment: well, i was ready to reply it and then came an alert another answer posted :) so took some more time and posted leisurely :)